# Prefix zero changes output in number addition

Tags: javascript

I tried to add two numbers in Javascript:

```
 var output;
 output = parseInt(a)+parseInt(b);
 alert(output);
```

It gives wrong `output` value, e.g. if `a = 015`, and `b = 05`. Why is this so? 
Expected result of above example should be 20.

Comment: Next time, also mention what the 'wrong output' is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you prefix your numbers with `0`, you're specifying them in base 8. `015` is therefore 13, and the sum is 18.

Use the second [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) argument to force a base:

```
var a = '015', b = '05';
var output;
output = parseInt(a, 10) + parseInt(b, 10);
alert(output); // alerts 20
```

Answer (score 0):

in many programming languages numbers starting with leading 0 indicate base 8 (octal) representation of the number. here you are giving octal numbers as input and expecting the output in decimal and thats the reason you say output is wrong (which is correct!! wrt octal addition)

```
solution 1 : you can add two octal numbers and convert the result to decimal  

solution 2 : convert the octal numbers to decimal and then add them
```