# why does console.log(0123); log 83?

Tags: javascript, console, console.log

Why does     `console.log(0123);` log the integer .    `83`? I'm not sure why it would and don't really have an idea either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does JavaScript output 16384 instead of 040000?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036122/why-does-javascript-output-16384-instead-of-040000)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prefix zero changes output in number addition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139648/prefix-zero-changes-output-in-number-addition)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's interpreted as an octal number, and octal 123 corresponds to decimal 83 (64 + 16 + 3).

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types):

> Leading `0` (zero) on an integer literal, or leading `0o` (or `0O`)
>   indicates it is in octal. Octal integers can include only the digits
>   0-7.

Comment: Only when there is a 0 in front or for every integer?

Comment: Only when there's a `0`, `0o` or `0O` in front.

Comment: Note that in strict mode you'll get `SyntaxError: Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.` for the literal `0123` but *not* for `0o123`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the leading 0 (zero) 0o or 0O on an integer indicates an octal number!!

Octal numbering system is used less nowadays and has almost disappeared as a digital base number system. Hexadecimal numbering system is so popular now!